# Web Chat with Facebook Integration

Tags: php, ajax, facebook

I need your help guys, I'm building my own web chat for my online radio site. I already have a AJAX PHP Web chat from Tutorialzine. I want to modify it. But i don't know where to start. I want it to integrate with Facebook. I want it instead of asking for username and email, there will be a button that says 'Connect to Facebook'. and the Profile Picture and Name of the user will automatically saved to the database. I really need it. And i want it to be moderated. Thank You! and God bless everyone! :)

ajax.php

```
<?php

/* Database Configuration. Add your details below */

$dbOptions = array(
'db_host' => 'localhost',
'db_user' => 'root',
'db_pass' => '',
'db_name' => 'chat'
);

/* Database Config End */


error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

require "classes/DB.class.php";
require "classes/Chat.class.php";
require "classes/ChatBase.class.php";
require "classes/ChatLine.class.php";
require "classes/ChatUser.class.php";

session_name('webchat');
session_start();

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){

// If magic quotes is enabled, strip the extra slashes
array_walk_recursive($_GET,create_function('&$v,$k','$v = stripslashes($v);'));
array_walk_recursive($_POST,create_function('&$v,$k','$v = stripslashes($v);'));
}

try{

// Connecting to the database
DB::init($dbOptions);

$response = array();

// Handling the supported actions:

switch($_GET['action']){

    case 'login':
        $response = Chat::login($_POST['name'],$_POST['email']);
    break;

    case 'checkLogged':
        $response = Chat::checkLogged();
    break;

    case 'logout':
        $response = Chat::logout();
    break;

    case 'submitChat':
        $response = Chat::submitChat($_POST['chatText']);
    break;

    case 'getUsers':
        $response = Chat::getUsers();
    break;

    case 'getChats':
        $response = Chat::getChats($_GET['lastID']);
    break;

    default:
        throw new Exception('Wrong action');
}

echo json_encode($response);
}
catch(Exception $e){
die(json_encode(array('error' => $e->getMessage())));
}

?>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// Run the init method on document ready:
chat.init();

});

var chat = {

// data holds variables for use in the class:

data : {
    lastID      : 0,
    noActivity  : 0
},

// Init binds event listeners and sets up timers:

init : function(){

    // Using the defaultText jQuery plugin, included at the bottom:
    $('#name').defaultText('Nickname');
    $('#email').defaultText('Email (Gravatars are Enabled)');

    // Converting the #chatLineHolder div into a jScrollPane,
    // and saving the plugin's API in chat.data:

    chat.data.jspAPI = $('#chatLineHolder').jScrollPane({
        verticalDragMinHeight: 12,
        verticalDragMaxHeight: 12
    }).data('jsp');

    // We use the working variable to prevent
    // multiple form submissions:

    var working = false;

    // Logging a person in the chat:

    $('#loginForm').submit(function(){

        if(working) return false;
        working = true;

        // Using our tzPOST wrapper function
        // (defined in the bottom):

        $.tzPOST('login',$(this).serialize(),function(r){
            working = false;

            if(r.error){
                chat.displayError(r.error);
            }
            else chat.login(r.name,r.gravatar);
        });

        return false;
    });

    // Submitting a new chat entry:

    $('#submitForm').submit(function(){

        var text = $('#chatText').val();

        if(text.length == 0){
            return false;
        }

        if(working) return false;
        working = true;

        // Assigning a temporary ID to the chat:
        var tempID = 't'+Math.round(Math.random()*1000000),
            params = {
                id          : tempID,
                author      : chat.data.name,
                gravatar    : chat.data.gravatar,
                text        :  text.replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;')
            };

        // Using our addChatLine method to add the chat
        // to the screen immediately, without waiting for
        // the AJAX request to complete:

        chat.addChatLine($.extend({},params));

        // Using our tzPOST wrapper method to send the chat
        // via a POST AJAX request:

        $.tzPOST('submitChat',$(this).serialize(),function(r){
            working = false;

            $('#chatText').val('');
            $('div.chat-'+tempID).remove();

            params['id'] = r.insertID;
            chat.addChatLine($.extend({},params));
        });

        return false;
    });

    // Logging the user out:

    $('a.logoutButton').live('click',function(){

        $('#chatTopBar > span').fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });

        $('#submitForm').fadeOut(function(){
            $('#loginForm').fadeIn();
        });

        $.tzPOST('logout');

        return false;
    });

    // Checking whether the user is already logged (browser refresh)

    $.tzGET('checkLogged',function(r){
        if(r.logged){
            chat.login(r.loggedAs.name,r.loggedAs.gravatar);
        }
    });

    // Self executing timeout functions

    (function getChatsTimeoutFunction(){
        chat.getChats(getChatsTimeoutFunction);
    })();

    (function getUsersTimeoutFunction(){
        chat.getUsers(getUsersTimeoutFunction);
    })();

},

// The login method hides displays the
// user's login data and shows the submit form

login : function(name,gravatar){

    chat.data.name = name;
    chat.data.gravatar = gravatar;
    $('#chatTopBar').html(chat.render('loginTopBar',chat.data));

    $('#loginForm').fadeOut(function(){
        $('#submitForm').fadeIn();
        $('#chatText').focus();
    });

},

// The render method generates the HTML markup 
// that is needed by the other methods:

render : function(template,params){

    var arr = [];
    switch(template){
        case 'loginTopBar':
            arr = [
            '<span><img src="',params.gravatar,'" width="23" height="23" />',
            '<span class="name">',params.name,
            '</span><a href="" class="logoutButton rounded">Logout</a></span>'];
        break;

        case 'chatLine':
            arr = [
                '<div class="chat chat-',params.id,' rounded"><span class="gravatar"><img src="',params.gravatar,
                '" width="23" height="23" onload="this.style.visibility=\'visible\'" />','</span><span class="author">',params.author,
                ':</span><span class="text">',params.text,'</span><span class="time">',params.time,'</span></div>'];
        break;

        case 'user':
            arr = [
                '<div class="user" title="',params.name,'"><img src="',
                params.gravatar,'" width="30" height="30" onload="this.style.visibility=\'visible\'" /></div>'
            ];
        break;
    }

    // A single array join is faster than
    // multiple concatenations

    return arr.join('');

},

// The addChatLine method ads a chat entry to the page

addChatLine : function(params){

    // All times are displayed in the user's timezone

    var d = new Date();
    if(params.time) {

        // PHP returns the time in UTC (GMT). We use it to feed the date
        // object and later output it in the user's timezone. JavaScript
        // internally converts it for us.

        d.setUTCHours(params.time.hours,params.time.minutes);
    }

    params.time = (d.getHours() < 10 ? '0' : '' ) + d.getHours()+':'+
                  (d.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0':'') + d.getMinutes();

    var markup = chat.render('chatLine',params),
        exists = $('#chatLineHolder .chat-'+params.id);

    if(exists.length){
        exists.remove();
    }

    if(!chat.data.lastID){
        // If this is the first chat, remove the
        // paragraph saying there aren't any:

        $('#chatLineHolder p').remove();
    }

    // If this isn't a temporary chat:
    if(params.id.toString().charAt(0) != 't'){
        var previous = $('#chatLineHolder .chat-'+(+params.id - 1));
        if(previous.length){
            previous.after(markup);
        }
        else chat.data.jspAPI.getContentPane().append(markup);
    }
    else chat.data.jspAPI.getContentPane().append(markup);

    // As we added new content, we need to
    // reinitialise the jScrollPane plugin:

    chat.data.jspAPI.reinitialise();
    chat.data.jspAPI.scrollToBottom(true);

},

// This method requests the latest chats
// (since lastID), and adds them to the page.

getChats : function(callback){
    $.tzGET('getChats',{lastID: chat.data.lastID},function(r){

        for(var i=0;i<r.chats.length;i++){
            chat.addChatLine(r.chats[i]);
        }

        if(r.chats.length){
            chat.data.noActivity = 0;
            chat.data.lastID = r.chats[i-1].id;
        }
        else{
            // If no chats were received, increment
            // the noActivity counter.

            chat.data.noActivity++;
        }

        if(!chat.data.lastID){
            chat.data.jspAPI.getContentPane().html('<p class="noChats">No chats yet</p>');
        }

        // Setting a timeout for the next request,
        // depending on the chat activity:

        var nextRequest = 1000;

        // 2 seconds
        if(chat.data.noActivity > 3){
            nextRequest = 2000;
        }

        if(chat.data.noActivity > 10){
            nextRequest = 5000;
        }

        // 15 seconds
        if(chat.data.noActivity > 20){
            nextRequest = 15000;
        }

        setTimeout(callback,nextRequest);
    });
},

// Requesting a list with all the users.

getUsers : function(callback){
    $.tzGET('getUsers',function(r){

        var users = [];

        for(var i=0; i< r.users.length;i++){
            if(r.users[i]){
                users.push(chat.render('user',r.users[i]));
            }
        }

        var message = '';

        if(r.total<1){
            message = 'No one is online';
        }
        else {
            message = r.total+' '+(r.total == 1 ? 'person':'people')+' online';
        }

        users.push('<p class="count">'+message+'</p>');

        $('#chatUsers').html(users.join(''));

        setTimeout(callback,15000);
    });
},

// This method displays an error message on the top of the page:

displayError : function(msg){
    var elem = $('<div>',{
        id      : 'chatErrorMessage',
        html    : msg
    });

    elem.click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
        elem.click();
    },5000);

    elem.hide().appendTo('body').slideDown();
}
};

// Custom GET & POST wrappers:

$.tzPOST = function(action,data,callback){
$.post('php/ajax.php?action='+action,data,callback,'json');
}

$.tzGET = function(action,data,callback){
$.get('php/ajax.php?action='+action,data,callback,'json');
}

// A custom jQuery method for placeholder text:

$.fn.defaultText = function(value){

var element = this.eq(0);
element.data('defaultText',value);

element.focus(function(){
    if(element.val() == value){
        element.val('').removeClass('defaultText');
    }
}).blur(function(){
    if(element.val() == '' || element.val() == value){
        element.addClass('defaultText').val(value);
    }
});

return element.blur();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to connect with facebook for the user name and picture then all you need to do is include the [Facebook Javascript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/), and then either use the [Login Button plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/) or use the [Client-Side authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/).

If you want to connect with the Facebook internal chat, then you can use the [Chat API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/) which has two authentication methods: [Facebook Platform](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/#platauth) and [Username/Password](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/#jabber).
If you want the first method (sounds like what you want) then you'll need to authenticate the user, either with the client side flow or the [server side flow](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) and ask for the ["xmpp_login" permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/).

There are php examples in the chat API documentation.

Comment: now, i can get facebook info. but my problem is how i will edit the PHP, AJAX & JAVASCRIPTS. i'm really confused. :(

Comment: You need to be more specific.

Comment: I can now get the infos from facebook. but, i also need to modify my PHP scripts. but i don't know what to modify. I can store data to my database. But it just stores to database. And nothing happens to my chatbox. :(

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, I'm not even a php programmer..  You'll need to figure that yourself. If you have more specific questions ask them, add code to it.

Comment: You posted code, but you have no specific question, more than that, I'm not into php. You have the php code facebook gave as example, try things yourself and come back with specific questions.

Comment: I want it to be like [this](http://barkadafm.org/). where there is a 'Connect to Facebook'. and [here's](http://blobfmcbox.co.cc) my created chatbox.

Comment: We have a different definition of what "specific" means. You asked a general question and I answered that. Now, it's up to you to experiment with it a bit and ask new questions which are specific. That's it for me for this thread.